# SqlServer Smo DropPeriodForSystemTime does not work

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have the follow code:

```
        public IEnumerable<string> GetScript()
        {
            //This is what we will return
            IEnumerable<string> scriptStrings = null;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
            this.Database = server.Databases[conn.Database];


            this.CopyAllObjects = false;
            this.CopyAllTables = false;
            //We only want to copy tables in a specific schema.
            List<Table> tablesToCopy = new List<Table>();
            foreach (Table t in this.Database.Tables)
            {
                var isInWhitelist = Whitelist
                    .Any(o => o.Name.Equals(t.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    && o.Schema.Equals(t.Schema, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                if (isInWhitelist)
                {
                    e
                    foreach (Column col in t.Columns)
                    {
                        col.Identity = false;
                        if (!col.InPrimaryKey)
                            col.Nullable = true;

                        col.GeneratedAlwaysType = GeneratedAlwaysType.None;

                    }


                    t.IsSystemVersioned = false;
                    t.HistoryTableName = string.Empty;
                    t.HistoryTableSchema = string.Empty;

                    tablesToCopy.Add(t);
                }
            }

            //Add specifically the tables we want which are from the schema we want
            this.ObjectList.AddRange(tablesToCopy);

            this.Options.NoCollation = true;
            this.Options.WithDependencies = false;
            this.Options.DriPrimaryKey = true;

            try
            {
                scriptStrings = this.ScriptTransfer().Cast<string>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We got an exception.");
                throw;
            }
            return scriptStrings;
        }
```

In essence I am just trying to take a temporal table and adjust it slightly. The focus for this post is removing temporalness.

The resulting script is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Deal](
        [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        SysStartTime,
        SysEndTime
        --fields removed 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Deals] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
        [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
        PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I don't understand why

> PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])

is still in the generated script. Even after calling

> t.DropPeriodForSystemTime();

Comment: A table with over 250 columns looks like a table (or database) that is severely suffering from denormalised data.